# change letters in strings

Tags: c, string, program-entry-point

Im doing a project to change the letter 'e' to 'a' and I still didnt have it right at all. My input is a file abc.txt:
'''

```
Im enne end
my ded is frenk
My mom is elycie Lou
```

'''
and my output is "My mom is alycie Lou" and in another line "My mom is alicya Lou".
Heres my code. Can anyone helps me?

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 3
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 50


int main()
{
   char line[MAX_LINE][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
   int i=0;
   FILE *arch;
   arch = fopen("abc.txt", "r");

   if (arch==NULL){
       printf("ERROR");
    }
    else{
        while (!feof(arch)){
            fgets(line[i], MAX_STRING_SIZE , arch);
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(arch);

    for ( i=0; line[i][MAX_STRING_SIZE]; ++i )
    {
        if ( line[i][MAX_STRING_SIZE] == 'e' )
        {
            line[i][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = 'a';

        }
    }printf("%s", line);

    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: You're reading all the lines into the same buffer, you end up with only the last line (you overwrite the previous one each time you read a new one).  Try dealing with each line in the while loop, right after reading it, instead of at the end.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop doesn't make sense... you're iterating over the characters in the string to do the substitutions, but printing the string every time you replace a character instead of just once after all the replacements are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple tips I'd consider implementing

First change your line declaration and also declare a counter that isn't `i`. We'll use both `i` and `counter`:

```c
char line[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
int counter = 0;
```

Then I would do this to the while loop that reads your file. Note that if `counter` ever equals or exceeds `MAX_LINE` then the loop will exit:

```c
while (((fgets(line, MAX_STRING_SIZE , arch)) != NULL) && counter < MAX_LINE)
{
    for ( i=0; line[i]; ++i )
    {
        if ( line[i] == 'e' )
        {
            line[i] = 'a';
        }
    }
    printf("%s", line);
    counter++;
}
```

Try these and see if it produces the desired behavior.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   char line[50];
   FILE *arch;
   arch = fopen("abc.txt", "r");

   if (arch==NULL){
       printf("ERROR");
```

better: `perror("abc.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

```
    }
    else{
        while (!feof(arch)){
```

see [while(!feof()) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

```
            fgets(line, 50 , arch);
            //store all strings from the file
        }
```

Nope! This does not *store* all strings from the file. This reads all strings fro the file, keeping the last one read in `line`. In your case, when the loop finishes (ignoring errors from `while(!feof())`), `line` will have the last line from the file.

```
    }
    fclose(arch);

    for ( i=0; line[i]; ++i )
    {
        if ( line[i] == 'e' )
        {
            line[i] = 'a';
            printf("%s", line);
```

Do you want to print the line as many times as there are `'e'`s there? If you just want to print it once after all `'e'`s have been converted move the `printf` line to after the end of the `for` loop

```
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: thanks for the touch! But if I do something like: fgets(line[i], 50 , arch) and i++ to store all the strings; its also wrong, right?

Comment: yes, that is wrong. You need an array of array (an array of strings) as in `char line[MAX_LINES][MAX_LENGTH];` and then you can read into `line[i]` inside the loop (and update `i++`)

Comment: I changed my code above and now it just reads the first line. Can you tell what is wrong, please? :)

Comment: @Mungo You are not processing the line immediately after reading it. To preserve PMG's answer I have included my own down below. Never use `feof()` but instead check to see if `fgets()` returns `NULL`

Comment: It worked! thank you so much! you guys helped me a lot. Im new on this thing and my professor told me to not use functions that we still havent seen on class. Thats why I used 'feof' because he only taught me that to read files. But the the way you put it its allowed to me to use and I didn't have thought of that. so thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do something with the contents of a whole file (change all `'e'`s to `'a'`s, delete all occurrences of the word `"very"`, ...) the first thing that you should think about is: **I'll read the file line-by-line, process each line until there are no more lines.** The most straight forward implementation of that thought is

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
// use FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r"); instead of stdin
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    process(line);
}
// remember to fclose(f) if not using stdin
```

*Remember this 4 (or 6) lines; you'll use them often.*

In your specific case (you want to print the line with `'a'`s instead of `'e'`s) the `process()` function could be something like:

```
void process(const char *line) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        if (line[i] == 'e') putchar('a');
        else putchar(line[i]);
    }
}
```

And that's it. Most of your program is done.

Add the proper `#include`s, error checking, `main()` and call it a day.